# Upgrade angular from 7 to 8

Tags: angular

I'm working on a new project, the startup stack is using angular version 7, I want to upgrade to the version 8. so I used the following command `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`.
After running the above command, my package.json file didn't change:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-webfonts": "^1.0.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.12.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.0",
    "@pioneer-code/pioneer-tree": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/async": "^2.0.50",
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
```

Comment: This blog may be usefull http://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2021/05/upgrade-angular-version-to-latest.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **ALSO YOU CAN USE THE FOLLOWING STEPS TO UPGRADE TO ANGULAR 9**
>
> **NOTE:**
>
> Instead of importing from `@angular/material`, you should import deeply
>   from the specific component. E.g. `@angular/material/button`. `ng update`
>   will do this automatically for you.

1- Upgrade your [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

2-Upgrade your Angular CLI:(uninstall the previous version then install new version)

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
# if npm version is < 5 then use `npm cache clean`
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

3-Upgrade your TypeScript: (It's better to upgrade global all dependencies)

```
npm update -g
```

4-Upgrade all the main dependencies of the project :

```
ng update @angular/cli
ng update @angular/core
ng update rxjs
```

If you are using Angular Material

```
ng update @angular/material
```

5-Upgrade the third party dependencies of the project:

```
npm install npm-check-updates -g
ncu -u
npm install
```

**The second command (ncu -u) changes the version number of packages in the package.json**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to run **`ng update --all`** to update all packages in your package.json

Also you have updated only the CLI, try all the steps as mentioned [`here`](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0)