# angular upgrade to 8 - errors

Tags: angular, webpack, angular8, angular-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my angular application to angular 8, webpack 4. 
Got below 3 errors:

   `TS2339: Property 'decorate' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.
   TS2539: Cannot assign to 'HeroComponent' because it is not a variable.
   TS2306: File 'C:/Users/SS/Documents/angularupgrade/Test/client/app/hero.component.ts' is not a module.`

My hero component:

```js
    //hero.component.ts
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<span>Hello {{name}}</span>`,
    })
    export class HeroComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Comment: Your HeroComponent looks good. It may be something missing or extra in it's module, app module or others.. Also from what angular version you migrating to 8? After which [migration step](https://update.angular.io/) it fails?

Comment: complete path to upgrade to **Angular 8** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393210/upgrade-angular-from-7-to-8/58393752#58393752