# Updated to Angular 8 now everything is broken

Tags: angular

I've wanted to update my Angular project from 7.3.6 (CLI) to the newest version (8.3.16). This failed. I did what the guide told me: https://update.angular.io/#7.2:8.0

I had to stash all changes because literally everything was red.

```
import { Injectable, HostListener, Directive, EventEmitter, Output, HostBinding, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

All of this imports were red. After the stash still nothing will work because some things are updated to 8.3.16 and some are not and the project is stuck on 7.2 I think.

`ng version` gives me:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.16
Node: 11.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.16
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.16
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.16
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.16
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.16
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.16
@angular/cdk                       7.3.7
@angular/cli                       8.3.16
@angular/material                  7.3.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.16
@schematics/angular                8.3.16
@schematics/update                 0.803.16
rxjs                               6.5.3
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.39.2
```

An example for errors are this ones:

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat'.
src/app/app.module.ts(32,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular-emojify'.
src/app/chat/chat.component.ts(13,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/chat/chat.component.ts(16,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/chat/chat.component.ts(19,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/chat/chatarea/chatarea.component.ts(27,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/chat/chatmessage/chatmessage.component.ts(50,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/chat/chatroom-list/chatroom-list.component.ts(34,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/registration/registration.component.ts(36,4): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/services/websocket.service.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/user/Git/chat/client/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
src/app/services/websocket.service.ts(25,17): error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/user/Git/chat/client/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'Subject'.
src/app/services/websocket.service.ts(202,15): error TS2339: Property 'Subject' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/Users/user/Git/chat/client/node_modules/rxjs/Rx")'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(64,29): error TS2339: Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(65,74): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(77,27): error TS2339: Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(78,72): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(96,29): error TS2339: Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(97,71): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(109,27): error TS2339: Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(110,69): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(126,27): error TS2339: Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
src/app/shared/validators/custom-validators.ts(127,116): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.
```

I'm not working alone on the project. The module angular-emojify has made problems while updating but I deleted it and tried to create the pipe myself.

I really don't know what to do because project and CLI does not match anymore.

Comment: `npm install --save rxjs-compat`, see also https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-handsontable/issues/505

Comment: It looks like you also updated rxjs version. All your observables will need to be changed. That is why  you are getting errors like .map() and .timer() do not exist. You'll now do somthing like someobservable.pipe(map())

Comment: follow all the steps in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393210/upgrade-angular-from-7-to-8/58393752#58393752

Comment: `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty` will you try?

Comment: rxjs-compat will probably make most of your errors go away, but the underlying issue of RxJS changing their syntax will not. If you are in a time crunch, rxjs-compat will help, otherwise you should consider moving your code to the most recent syntax

Comment: @AbolfazlR Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating. when I want to do ng update. Had also a powerShell bug now

Comment: @Igor u are right. Installed rxjs-compat again works. Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.16) is greater than your local version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used. But it works.

Comment: @CptDayDreamer - Its good that you fixed your issue but your app is still at version 7. So when you try next time to update to 8, make sure you update your code to RxJS 6 first and then follow the steps of Official Angular update guide for Advanced Apps.

Comment: @Saloo i've updated everything to version 8. The problem were the changes that came with RxJS 6 with the map operator, timer and Rx.Subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Official Guide clearly says :

Angular Update Guide | 7.2 -> 8.0 for Advanced Apps

**Before Updating**

- If you use the legacy HttpModule and the Http service, switch to
  HttpClientModule and the HttpClient service. HttpClient simplifies
  the default ergonomics (you don't need to map to JSON anymore) and
  now supports typed return values and interceptors. Read more on
  angular.io.
- **Once you and all of your dependencies have updated to

  RxJS 6, remove rxjs-compat.**
- If you use the Angular Service worker,
  migrate any versionedFiles to the files array. The behavior is the
  same.

I think you missed the step to first update your code to use latest RxJS 6 compliant.