# Typescript errors when accessing to @angular/core packages

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I just updated an Ionic app from Angular 7 to Angular 8, and I'm having a weird error:

[image]

As you can see, I can't access any of the typical classes stored in the @angular/core module. Same happens for other angular modules, like `@angular/router`. These are the dependencies of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.19",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/spinner-dialog": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/stripe": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.11.5",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.38.0",
    "@types/parse": "^2.2.15",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^7.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-native-spinner": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-res": "^0.8.1",
    "core-js": "^3.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "parse": "^2.9.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0",
    "recursive-readdir": "^2.2.2",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "sharp": "^0.23.2",
    "whitelist": "^1.0.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^8.3.19",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.3.19",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/chartjs": "0.0.31",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.7",
    "codelyzer": "~5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.2",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Thank you!

edit: Needless to say, I ran `npm install` and actually, I can access the modules, but inside them I have various subfolders: esm2015, es5, fesm2015, fesm5, schematics... this shouldn't appear here, right?

Comment: see this complete link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393210/upgrade-angular-from-7-to-8/58393752#58393752

Comment: you might just have to reload your VSCode window

Comment: @MattWalterspieler This worked! Post it as an answer and I'll set it as the proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reload your VSCode window:

`cmd + shift + p` (macos) or `ctrl +shift+ p`(windows) then type  and select `Developer: reload window`

Answer (score 0):

Try one thing.

First remove your `package-lock.json` file, and reinstall all node modules